# Determining the genus of the compact orientable surface $S =\{[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3]\in \Bbb RP^3 : x^2_0+ x^2_1- x^2_2-x^2_3=0\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, surfaces, projective-space

Consider the subset $S =\{[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3]\in \Bbb RP^3 : x^2_0+ x^2_1-x^2_2-x^2_3=0\}$ of $\Bbb RP^3$. Clearly $S$ is an embedded submanifold of $\Bbb RP^3$ of codimension $1$, so it is a compact orientable (since $\Bbb RP^3$ is compact and orienatble) surface. Hence it must be diffeomorphic to either $S^2$ or a connected sum of tori. I want to determine its genus.

Comment: This is a "ruled surface".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Can you make a linear change of coordinates in $\Bbb R^4$ so that the equation becomes
$$y_0y_2+y_1y_3=0?$$

Answer (score 0):

**Not a solution, but a hint to get you thinking more in the right direction.**

"Clearly  is an embedded submanifold of $\Bbb RP^3$ of codimension 1, so it is a compact orientable (since ℝ3 is compact and orienatble) surface."

I think that perhaps your approach went off the rails here, because $\Bbb R P^2$ is an embedded submanifold of $\Bbb RP^3$ of codimension 1, but is not orientable.  ($\Bbb RP^2$ can, for instance, be seen as the subset where $x_3 = 0$.)

Comment: You're right. But the surface $S$ is indeed orientable: Define $f:\Bbb R^4-0 \to \Bbb R$ by $f(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_0^2+x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2$. Then $f$ is a submersion, and $f$ induces a quotient map $\bar{f}:\Bbb RP^3\to \Bbb R$ which is again a submersion, since the projeciton $\Bbb R^4-0\to \Bbb RP^3$ is a submersion. Now $S=\bar{f}^{-1}(0)$ is orientable, being a level set of a regular value of a smooth function.

Comment: Perhaps I need more coffee, but I don't see how $f$ passes to the quotient, for $f(1,0,0,0) = 1^2 = 1$, but $f(2,0,0,0) = 2^2 = 4$. I'm potentially willing to believe that $S$ is orientable, but so far, at least, I'm not willing to believe the reasons you've given.

Comment: You are again right. I think I first need to check orientability

Comment: @AnginaSeng Where are you seeing complex subvarieties?